# Prove that $a^2(p-q)(p-r)+ b^2(q-r)(q-p)+ c^2(r-p)(r-q) =4(\delta)^2$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If $p$,$q$,$r$ are the perpendiculars drawn from the vertices of a triangle ABC upon any straight line meeting the sides externally in D,E,F. 
[image: Prove that $a^2(p-q)(p-r)+ b^2(q-r)(q-p)+ c^2(r-p)(r-q) =4(\delta)^2$]
where a,b,c are the sides opposite to angles A,B,C in Triangle ABC and delta represents the area of the triangle ABC.
Also prove that EF= $(2pq)/((p-q)(p-r))$
I have tried this problem in this way but couldn't solve the problem, can anyone help me from here??
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let G,H,I be the foot of perpendiculars from A,B and C. GH=x GI=y check the following pictures carefully.we have broke the figure into rectangles and applied Pythagoras theorem...breaking the figure and applying Pythagoras theorem is very important[image: check the following carefully[notice how we simplified[![][1]][image]

[image: []][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbNeH.jpg)

[image: notice how greatly we arrived at the result]

Comment: Please do not post a series of pics. Answer using LaTeX

Comment: How to answer using latex?? And how to draw figures in computer

Comment: Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax

Comment: Got it, but how do you draw figures in computer?

Comment: See other posts. You still see quite a variety

Comment: I know there is an app called geogebra, but how do u save it JPEG format??

Comment: Take a screenshot.

Comment: @VamsiSpidy you can export the GeoGebra to jpg format and save it.

Answer (score -1):

The following pictures explain how we found out EF using similar triangles approach..we also used the fact that the area of our triangle + a trapezium is equal to the area of 2 trapeziums[see[[image: ][1]]][[image: check my approach carefully]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wij8i.jpg)